# Set the height of a QTreeView to height of N rows

Tags: qt, layout, qtreeview

I want to use a QTreeView (PyQt5) and set its height according to the number of first-level entries the model has.

This is because I don't know how many entries there will be to show, and I don't want to spend the default height of the widget when there is only one entry.

So what I need and didn't find yet is a way to

- determine the height of the rows (they will be single-line strings so I can set it to uniform height if that helps)
- set the exact height of the QTreeView in relation to a multiple of the row's height.

(I'll experiment with minimum and maximum numbers and padding if necessary)

Comment: If you want to manipulate height you will have to use a delegate item and to override his size hint function.

Comment: Hm, I don't want to manipulate the height of the *item*, only retrieve it and then set the height of the QTreeView as a whole.